# How to use the bash shell with Python in place of /bin/sh

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, python

I have commands that could be executed in a terminal, but I want to execute them directly from my python script, except that my script it launches the commands in `/bin/sh`, and my terminal is bash.

**Examples**

in my script python:

```py
!macommande

/bin/sh: macommande: command not found
```

while on the terminal:

```bsh
[user@user] $ macommande

bash: macommande: command not found
```

p.s.: my commands work well on `bash`, but not on `/bin/sh`:

```py
!ll

/bin/sh: ll: command not found
```

while on the terminal:

```bsh
[user@user] $ ll

rw-rw-r--  1 1614 Apr 10 16003 example
drwxrwxr-x  3 4096 Apr 10 10:13 config
drwxrwxr-x  3 4096 Apr 10 10:09 demo00
```

Comment: you can use bash to run the command by prepending /bin/bash like so: `/bin/bash macommande`

Comment: This question should explain which shell `/bin/sh` actually is on this system, because it appears that `/bin/sh` _is_ the Bourne Again shell and the underlying premise of the question is false.  That error message is in the form printed by the Bourne Again shell.

Comment: `ll` is an alias, defined in `~/.bashrc`. Do other commands work e.g. `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have preceded your shell command with the exclamation point, that indicates to me that you are using Ipython. If that is true, I would recommend that you read that article: [Ipython and Shell commands](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html).

The short answer is that ‘list long’ or ‘ll’ command will work if you don’t use ‘!’ the exclamation point. I suspect that your ‘macommande’ will work also.

To enter a multi-line bash command you can use ‘%%bash’. Hope that helps.